# Placing orders without transmitting them with IBpy?

Tags: interactive-brokers, ibpy

I am new to `IBpy` and I am wondering if there is any way to place an order without transmitting it and waiting for a human input to actually transmit the order?

I am using `placeOrder` to place orders but I can't find a way of placing them without transmitting them.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set m_transmit to False in your order.

```
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
from ib.ext.Order import Order
from ib.opt import ibConnection, message
from time import sleep

def watchAll(msg):
    print(msg)

con = ibConnection(clientId=1)
con.registerAll(watchAll)
con.connect()
sleep(1)

fx = Contract()
fx.m_secType = "CASH" 
fx.m_symbol = "USD"
fx.m_currency = "CAD"
fx.m_exchange = "IDEALPRO"
con.reqMktData(1,fx,"",False)

ord = Order()
ord.m_orderType = 'MKT'
ord.m_totalQuantity = 100000
ord.m_action = 'BUY'
ord.m_transmit = False
con.placeOrder(1234,fx,ord)
```

Your TWS will have a row like this
[image]
Notice the transmit button if you want to transmit from TWS.

Then you can resend the same order using the same orderId but set m_transmit to True.

```
ord.m_transmit = True
con.placeOrder(1234,fx,ord)
```

Then it get's transmitted and TWS will show the fill, also the order message callbacks will get printed in the simple `def watchAll(msg)`
[image]

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Did't know about the `m_transmit`. Thanks a lot